# Select option selected dynamically: Using JSP + Jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a Page with 4 links and each links looks like below.

```
 <a href="contact.jsp?subject=one">Link1</a>
 <a href="contact.jsp?subject=two">Link2</a>
 <a href="contact.jsp?subject=three">Link3</a>
 <a href="contact.jsp?subject=Four">Link4</a>
```

The contact.jsp is just a form which has a text box and a  with 4 options. Whenever the user clicks on the links above it should take to the contact form with the actual subject option selected in line with the query parameter(subject) passed in the HREF link.

Is it possible to do in Jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have the subject listed in the URL you can get it with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getURLParameter(name) {
        return decodeURI(
            (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
        );
    }
    $('#mySelect').val(getURLParameter('subject'));
});
```

Then just make sure the value of the select box options corespond to the possibilities "one, two, three" and "four".

In response to your comment below, if you'd like to then check the value and potentially show a file upload input, the code might look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getURLParameter(name) {
        return decodeURI(
            (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
        );
    }
    $('#mySelect').val(getURLParameter('subject'));
    if($('#mySelect').val() == 'three'){
        $('#myFileUpload').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have one more problem because of this. In the actual form I have a upload field which is visible based on the option selected. The above fix works when a user clicks the link it takes to the form and the right option is selected automatically but the upload  field doesnt show up. This works when the user selects the option on the form itself. DO i need to change the event?

Comment: Thanks Chris. Will get back to you with your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

A selected option is identified by presence of `selected` attribute in the HTML `<option>` element.

Just let JSP generate the desired HTML accordingly.

```
<select name="subject">
    <option value="one" ${param.subject == 'one' ? 'selected' : ''}>one</option>
    <option value="two" ${param.subject == 'two' ? 'selected' : ''}>two</option>
    <option value="three" ${param.subject == 'three' ? 'selected' : ''}>three</option>
    <option value="four" ${param.subject == 'four' ? 'selected' : ''}>four</option>
</select>
```

No need for weird JS/jQuery workarounds. They're meant for progressive enhancement anyway. In other words, your webapp should be designed/developed in such way that it retains the core functionality even with JS disabled.

Comment: This is better than my answer, I just dont' know Java.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I will try this and let you know.